# How to implement user based security in the firebase database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

This is the database for example:

```
"Messages" : {
      "Message1" : {
               "Uid" : "sampleid1"
                "Text" : "hi"
                },
       "Message2" : {
                "Uid" : "sampleid2"
                "Text" : " hello"
                }
  }
```

I want only those users to read the messages whose uid is equal to the `Uid` field of `Message#`.

The structure of database given in firebase documentation(i.e. using user id based messages in the database where the node of each message represents the uid of the user who sent the message) doesn't achieve the goal of my project as I need to know the uid of the user who sent the message each time any user sends a message.
Therefore, please suggest the rules that would help me achieve my task as mentioned in this question
Also, when I applied certain rules on the above structure of database, I couldn't read any data because 'firebase rules are not filters'. 
Please ignore the syntax and format of json written in above example as it is just for reference
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Structure your data so:

```
"messages" : {
  "<receiver_uid>" : {
      "msg_1" : {
         "text" : "Hello world...",
         "uid" : "<sender_uid>"
      }
      // more msgs for this receiver ...
   }
}
```

the rules should be something like

```
{ 
  "rules" : {
    "messages" : {
      "$receiver" : {
        ".read" : "auth.uid == $receiver", // only receiver shall read
        ".write" : "auth != false" // any authenticated user can write
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No sir, this structure won't work for me. As I need to attach on child changed listeners to messages and then on child added listener to receiver uid, it won't fetch me the uid of the person who has received the message. This is what I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: Could you please tell a bit more what you actually would like to achieve? I do not understand that issue.